# Using async/await but UI still hangs using Caliburn.Micro BindableCollection AddRange

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, async-await, caliburn.micro

I have facing a problem where my UI is unresponsive for a one sec or so and I guess its my Async/Await skills that are not upgraded to latest version.

Its a WPF app using the Caliburn Micro Framework. What I have found sofar is that my UI is responsive while it is seaching packages (Nuget.Core) and its when the Task have returned with a list of elements and its doign AddRange on the bindable collection. (Its on a feed with max 5 elements, so I dont see why it should take more then a few ms to put that few elements into the collection.

```
    protected override async void OnActivate()
    {
        base.OnActivate();
        this.PropertyChanged += PluginManagerViewModel_PropertyChanged;            

        IsBusy = true;
        var list = await SearchPackages();
        this.Packages.AddRange(list);
        IsBusy = false;

    }
    async void  PluginManagerViewModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.PropertyName)
        {
            case "SelectedVersion":
            case "SelectedSortBy":
               var list= await SearchPackages();
               this.Packages.AddRange(list);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    }
    public BindableCollection<IPackage> Packages { get; set; }
    private Task<IEnumerable<IPackage>> SearchPackages()
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
                SelectedSortBy.OrderBy(
                (_manager.SourceRepository
                .Search("", SelectedVersion != "Stable")))
                .AsEnumerable()
                .Where(PackageExtensions.IsListed));
    }
```

Here is the listview:

```
<ListView ScrollViewer.PanningMode="VerticalFirst"
                   ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                   ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                   ScrollViewer.PanningRatio="0.5"
                   x:Name="Packages">
                   <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid cal:Bind.Model="{Binding}">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="Description" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,27.96,136,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="62.04"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="Title" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top"  FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,10,136,0"/>
                            <Button Content="Install" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="121" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,10,10,0"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" x:Name="Version" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  Margin="0,32.96,10,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" TextAlignment="Right" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                   </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

Comment: Do you have any complex `ItemTemplate` for displaying these items?

Comment: `this.Packages.AddRange(list)` will cause UI to update its visual. May be that's why?

Comment: Nothing heavy on the UI. Just a simple UserControll. (But using Caliburn.Micro, maybe its slow at finding the usercontrol at each addded item?)

Comment: Can you check if replacing `BindableCollection` with `ObservableCollection` makes any difference?

Comment: It made no difference with ObservableCollection.

Comment: Try to set **Task.Run(() => ...).ConfigureAwait(false);**. Because of you use bindable collection from Caliburn there is no needs to call invoke in main thread explicitly (it's done in bindable collection).

Comment: I have profiled and used some Task.Delays and the conclussion is clear that the UI is responsive when async stuff is running. It hangs at the point where it start adding the data to the collections and updating the UI. I have even tried doing manual forloops and adding one by one with small Task.Delays in between and it seems to hang whenever UI needs to be updated. I will update the UI code in the question just to show that its simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a perfect solution but atleast my UI is responsive again.

```
    private async Task UpdatePackagesCollection()
    {

        IsBusy = true;
        var list = await SearchPackages().ConfigureAwait(false);    
        this.Packages.Clear();
        IsBusy = false;
        foreach (var p in list)
        {
            await App.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
            {
                Packages.Add(p);

            }, DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);
        }  
    }
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it (probably) will execute `Clear` and set `IsBusy` on a thread pool thread (raising the property/collection changed events off the UI thread), which is a no-no for most MVVM frameworks. The fact that this affects your UI responsiveness leads me to believe it's some listener that's misbehaving (or you just have a *ton* of items already in the collection). I recommend creating a test case (with stub `SearchPackages`) that you execute in a loop and use a profiler to find the actual problem code.

Comment: SearchPackages is not the problem. It works as intended. There is no more then 5 elements. In WPF it will take care of using the UI Thread and using it elseware i can just dispatch the Busy on UI thread. But your are right, would be better to find the real problem.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that `SearchPackages` is the problem. I was suggesting that event listeners on `Packages` are likely the problem. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Okay. I have down prioritised it right now to find the source as I want to get the first version of my application ready and then I can make time to see if this can be done better. After all above do have a nice user experience and it works in my setup.